# PHP PDO array, only result one row

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

The result keep showing one row, any idea? All answers on other questions  don't seem to help..

```
<?php     
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY user_id ASC');
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach($row as $row_user) {

 ?>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
  <div class="flex-direction-column animated fadeInUp">
   <div class="notification">
    <div class="row">
    <span>pic</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <span>name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <span>nim</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <span>occupation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <span>description</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="notification">
    <div class="row-inner">
    <span><?php echo $row_user['user_pic']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row-inner">
    <span><?php echo $row_user['user_fullname']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row-inner">
    <span><?php echo $row_user['user_nim']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row-inner">
    <span><?php echo $row_user['user_occupation']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row-inner">
    <span><?php echo $row_user['user_desc']; ?></span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php
    }   
  ?>
```

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: Also. Why is there a back tick at the beginning of the php? Before the "<?php" tag.

Comment: No, the tick doesn't matter @McStuffins

Comment: Just curious why the back tick was there.

Comment: its only showing one row, there are 5 row id @McStuffins

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM members` and `var_dump($response);`

Comment: @chris85 yes i have, i didn't see any different between fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and fetchAll();

Comment: @McStuffins var_dump($row); ? https://s23.postimg.org/sxfflynft/this.png

Comment: Did you replace the query?

Comment: wait, i just print without front-end, and its all showing up.. @McStuffins

Comment: idk, if css could affected to this code.. Thanks for your help @McStuffins

Comment: Sounds like it was a front end issue, not PHP. You should always look at the generated code when debugging.

Comment: Glad to of helped...